# Moxtra chat functionality is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to embedded chat functionality with my application.

Step 1: Register my app on Moxtra site.

Step 2: Downloaded sample program from https://gist.github.com/moxtradeveloper/e1a023522b87b81f116d and rename as "moxtra-chat.html"

Step 3: Added my client id and secret key at the required place.

Step 4: Created one more html ["moxtra-user.html"] as above to create user in moxtra and added unique_id = "abc";

Step 5: Run the "moxtra-user.html" and call the get_token() API. [For now I blocked start_chat method]

Step 6: Added unique_id="pqr" in global location and replace unique_id = "abc" in chat_option of "moxtra-chat.html"

Step 7: And executed moxtra-chat.html, access_tocken get generated and start_chat(access_token) also invoke and then I will get the following error.

**TypeError: d is undefined             mx.base.js:22993**

Same example is working for meet API but not for chat api.
Please do let me know, how can I run chat functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moxtra team fixed issue and its working now...